# Get digital signature on word document using DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

After a signature request with a word document (.docx) has been sent to demo server using v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes API, I get envelope id. I can use the envelope id to get the recipient view via URL that looks like ‘https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=xxx’.

My questions are:

•   After signed, I only get a signed PDF, is it possible to get the signature on the original word document?

•   After signed, I will get a notification through callback URL, can we pass some parameters to that URL?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

• After signed, I only get a signed PDF, is it possible to get the signature on the original word document?

- No, the final output is a PDF.

• After signed, I will get a notification through callback URL, can we pass some parameters to that URL?

- If you are referring to the returnURL value (the URL we re-direct the signers web browser to), then yes. This is your URL so you can customize it.

Comment: If you need the original Word document to be digitally signed, the [CoSign Central from DocuSign](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/electronic-signature/digital-signature/cosign-central) product will do this for you.